# File download iframe absolute vs relative address

Tags: javascript, download

We are using this code in javascript for downloading files via iframe and it works well:

```
function initDownload(){
var path = "path/to/song.mp3", name = "song.mp3";
document.getElementById('myiframe').src = "dl.php?path="+path+"&name="+name;
}

<iframe id="myiframe" style="position: absolute; left: -10000px; display: none;" src=""></iframe>
<a href="#" onClick="initDownload(); return false;">download</a>
```

Here is dl.php file:

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$name\"");
}
if(isset($_GET['path'])){
   $path = str_replace(' ', '%20', $_GET['path']);
   readfile($path);
}
exit;
```

?>

Song path is set as absolute url and this works well. There have been a case when this havent worked, and after some testing, it turned out that only relative url was accepted (worked) on that particular server. 
Is there a reason why an absolute url wouldnt worked on some servers, maybe some php setting or something?

Answer (score 0):

You should check, what you are doing in dl.php file with path, here `html` and `javascript` will work on all servers the same way. Quite shure the problem is in the way `php` getting to the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited the post to add php file content.

Comment: As I was thinking, your php is not ok. You should try to add `$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);` to filename or something similar to detect the real absolute path to the file.

Comment: But I set path to the file with javascript and the path is correct, if I load (for example mp3) file in browser it plays. Still, can you show me how the php code should look like after your addition?

Comment: is php file in the same directory where mp3 file is?

Comment: you need to add another php file in the directory where mp3 files are or build the code so you can add absolute path.
Example:
/dir/dl.php
/dir/mp3/play.mp3
Then you need to generate realpath in dl.php and add to realpath /mp3/
JavaScript can't get absolute path because it's not server-based.

Comment: I do get proper path because I send variables I need from php to javascript. (since I am reading the folder or mp3 files with php anyway.) And like I said, if I enter the path I generate in browser, music player.

Comment: for file you need a server absolute path, it's not the same as JavaScript is making.